# Classifying without the target varibale

Tags: python

dataset of 5 months of monthly payment and a bucket telling us where the customer falls under. I have to predict the behavior of the customer good or bad

1271    D-3
1172    D+6
3038    D-3
4057    D+6
5059    D+3
4151    D
911     D
1780    D+15
1368    D+3

Answer (score 1):

if customer falls under then it is bad customer, so first you have to create a new list of output based on that condition. this will be your target variable

Comment: I couldn't fix the criteria to decide if the customer falls under or not because monthly payments were totally different. Thank you for your response